# Perl scp a remote directory and show the progress

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl scripting. With my below code, i am trying to loop this system call command to print (====) until the remote scp is done. But it turns out the loop does not get executed until the scp is complete. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$server = "myserver.com" 
$download_from = "/var/tmp";
$download_to = "/tmp"
chomp ($scp_user = <STDIN>);
$rc = system ("scp -r ${scp_user}\@${server}:{download_from} ${download_to} >> $logfile 2>&1");

my count = 0;
while (( $rc == 0) && ( $count < 120 ))
{
 print "=" ;
 sleep 5;
 $count = $count = 1;
 $rc = system ("scp -r ${scp_user}\@${server}:{download_from} ${download_to} >> $logfile 2>&1");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and perl.  Please include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html`) at the top of EVERY perl script.  It's the #1 thing that you can do to make yourself a better programmer and additionally make your programming life easier.

Comment: One of Perl's strengths is the availability of modules that do most things imaginable, so that you don't have to do it all over again. In this case something like [Net::SCP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SCP) might do what you want. If you really *do* want to run the `scp` command yourself, then I suggest something like [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3) instead of piping within `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is calling scp (in a subshell that gets started by the system call) when that finishes you check the exit code and if it's zero (which typically indicates success) you call it again.

BTW the line `$count = $count = 1;` is not incrementing as I assume you intended, it's just setting it to 1. You probably meant to write `$count++;`

I assume that you want to print out an equals sign every 5 seconds until the command completes. To do this you would need to run the command in parallel and check when it has finished.

I guess that your code never stops and just prints out equals signs every 5 seconds or so until you get bored and kill it

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use threads to copy the file while your program prints the progress.

Here is an example...

```
use Config;
use threads;
$Config{useithreads} or die('Recompile perl with threads to run this program');

$| = -1;  # non buffered output.

my $thread = threads->create(\&copy_file);  # Spawn the thread.
while (threads->list(threads::runing)) {    # While it is running.
  print "=";                                #   show the progress.
  sleep 1;                                  #   sleep to give it a chance to run.
}
$thread->join();                            # Cleanup the thread. 

# Function to do the file copy.
sub copy_file {
  system 'scp /tmp/junk.junk localhost:/tmp/junk.bunk >/dev/null 2>&1';
}
```

Here is another solution which uses fork instead of threads...
.. and handles the password. (although I really do recommend using public keys)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SCP::Expect;
use Term::ReadKey;

use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

my $user;
my $pw;

print "Enter Username: ";
chomp($user = <STDIN>);
ReadMode('noecho');
print "Enter Password: ";
chomp($pw = <STDIN>);
ReadMode('restore');

my $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new;
   $scpe->login($user, $pw);

$| = -1;

my $pid = fork;
if ($pid) {
    print "parent\n";
} elsif ($pid == 0) {

  $scpe->scp('/tmp/junk','localhost:/tmp/junk2');
  exit 0;

} else {
    die  "Couldnt fork\n";
}
my $child;
do {
   $child = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);
   sleep 1;
   print "-";
} while $child >= 0;
print "\nFile has been copied.\n";
```

Comment: Thanks John,                                                                              looks like the threads module is not in this version of perl i am using. Perl 5.8.4

Comment: # perldoc threads                                                                     No documentation found for "threads".

Comment: Can I use fork instead of threads since threads module does not seem to be installed with perl version I am running?

Comment: Perl 5.8.4 I am using does not appear to have threads module. Can this be accomplished using fork instead?

Comment: Maybe.  I tried that first but my mac doesn't seem to be able to do a non blocking wait, so I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: thanks John,                                                         the one with the fork you showed above almost works. The scp uses STDIN for the user password. So when i run your fork, it starts to print ----- before the user inputs the password. If it can only show the progress with ---- after the user password is entered, that would be nice.

Comment: Your should never put a password in a script. Put your public key in the authorized_keys file instead.